# Gettting rid of the constant in integration

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

So we have an integral $$F(a):=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-ay}\sin(y)}{y}dy$$

$$f(a,y):= \frac{e^{-ay}\sin(y)}{y} $$

We can bound the inner function with: $|f(a,y)|\leq e^{-ay}$

However let's say that we know that $F(a) = -\arctan(a)+c$, where $c$ is some constant. We need to get rid of it.

$\textbf{I do not understand the following and would need some explanation:}$

So what we have done is: $|F(a)|\leq\int_0^{\infty}e^{-ay}dy = \frac{1}{a}$

As $a \rightarrow \infty$ we get $|\lim_{a\rightarrow 
 \infty}F(a)|\leq 0 \iff |\lim_{a\rightarrow 
 \infty}F(a)| = 0 $

So because $F(a) = -\arctan(a)+c$ as $a \rightarrow \infty$ we get $-\pi/2 +c = 0 \iff c = \pi/2$

And we get the result for $F(a)$.

My primary question is:
$\textbf{Why does the inner function bound also imply the same integral}$
$\textbf{bound?}$

And the explanation of the process above..

Answer (score 1):

Start by using this absolute value inequality for integrals:

$$\left\vert\int\limits_{0}^\infty f(x)dx\right\vert\leq \int\limits_{0}^\infty |f(x)|dx$$

Applying this to your problem gives,

$$|F(a)|\leq \int\limits_{0}^\infty |f(a,y)|dy$$

The integrand is $|f(a,y)|$ which is bounded by $e^{-ay}$; both of these functions are nonnegative. If the final step,

$$\int\limits_{0}^\infty |f(a,y)|dy \leq \int\limits_{0}^\infty e^{-ay}dy$$

doesn't hold then it must be true that

$$\int\limits_{0}^\infty e^{-ay} - |f(a,y)|dy < 0 $$

which contradicts the fact that $e^{-ay}\geq |f(a,y)|$.